# Core Data model design or architecture

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm planning to use Core Data to store my app's data. However, when I tried to design the architecture of the model entities, I found that the most core data tutorials mixed the "fetch data"、"insert data"、"delete data" with ViewControllers. Doesn't such operations be put in model's implementation according to the information system design principle??
For example, there is a base ModelClass:

```
class BaseModel {
 var modelName: String!

// insert
 func insertNewObjectToModel(managedContext:NSManagedObjectContext)->BaseModel {

   return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(modelName, inManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! BaseModel
 }


// get 
 func fetchObject(predicate: NSPredicate)...


// delete
 func deleteObject(object:BaseModel)...

}
```

And then I have a model "Student" inherit from BaseModel class, so it inherits its methods of inserting, querying, deleting and so on. Then in ViewController class, if user wants to add a new object, just call `student.insertNewObject(context)`.
 I'm really confused about whether such design or encapsulation works. I have read Ray's 《Core Data by Tutorials》, and also read the Apple's Core Data examples. But it seemed that they all put model related operations in ViewController.
For example, I picked a few lines of code from Ray's book:

```
  func populateDealsCountLabel() {
        // 1
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Venue")
        fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

        // 2
        let sumExpressionDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
        sumExpressionDesc.name = "sumDeals"

        // 3
        sumExpressionDesc.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "specialCount")])

        sumExpressionDesc.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType

        // 4
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [sumExpressionDesc]

        // 5 
        do {
            let results = try coreDataStack.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSDictionary]

            let resultDict = results.first!
            let numDeals = resultDict["sumDeals"]
            numDealsLabel.text = "\(numDeals!) total deals"
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

English is not my tongue language, so I'm not sure if you seeing the question understand what my description want to express. But I'm hoping for your comments and answers! Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I use core data,I put the logic code in extension.And I use this lib to reduce some work.https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/tree/master/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject

Comment: Tutorials are rarely concerned with best-practice in any sense of the word.  They are trying to teach specific concepts, techniques or APIs.  When writing "real" code, always follow whatever you consider to be good practice and design.

Comment: http://objc.io does more to promote good quality while teaching features too. I agree with @Avi, most tutorials and Apple sample code are a mess from the point of view of architecture / correctness / knowledge allocation.

Comment: @Leo, thanks for your suggestion, I will consider using MagicalRecord at a later time. But for now I‘m wondering if I implement the Core Data models myself, what is the best architecture?

Comment: @Avi, I understand what you mean, thanks. However, can you give me some advice on what I thought about the architecture. According to [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1) -Entity inheritance, it seems that the architecture I consider to be good will affect my app's performance.o(╯□╰)o

Comment: @Wain, yes, [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-models-and-model-objects/) really has written a lot of articles with good quality╰(￣▽￣)╮.As my apply to Avi, for my situation, what should I  do to improve my app's core data model? Thank you~

Comment: Don't inherit, use an extension

Comment: @Wain do you mean extends NSManagedObject?

Comment: @WeiweiYin The performance hit that Apple refer to arises when you use parent entities in the data model (because parent and all child entities share one SQL table), but you can adopt your design without using parent entities: just specify the relevant subclass of BaseModel as the class for each entity.

Comment: @pbasdf Really? hahaha...thanks, I just planned to not use BaseModel class with repeating a lot of code and then I saw your answer. I will have a try~~ Good luck to all you guys!